# XML ready, Java unsuccessful

Tags: android

I have a problem with this piece of code. I have the ids registered in my XML, but the code isn't working. The main is in red, the add_photo is in red, the targeturi and targetimage are all in red (Everything in red is in italic).

```
    setContentView(R.layout.*main*);
    Button buttonAddPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.*add_photo*);
    textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.*targeturi*);
    targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.*targetimage*);

XML: 

<TextView
       android:text= "Thot of The Day!"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/text_shout_out"



        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Photo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_shout_out"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="131dp"
        android:onClick="Image"/>
```

Comment: Post your layout file too.

Comment: are you really using asterisk in your code ?

Comment: Edit your question with the layout file. Don't put it as comment.

Comment: No. It's just for here. To make the point of what needs to be done.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this, so I didn't know I could edit the question

Comment: What is the name of your layout file? Is it main or activity_main?

Comment: Yea, ik about that. I didn't declare them because the button variable didn't activate in the Java folder, so I was focused on getting that working before starting with the other two

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of your activity layout is activity_main, you need to do

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You don't have TextViews with id of R.id.targeturi and R.id.targetimage anywhere in your layout file. You need to put them in your layout first.
Also, you need to declare your TextViews(unless you have declared them already before onCreate())

```
TextView textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targeturi);
TextView targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);
```

Comment: The setContentView(R.layout activity_main) didn't work

Comment: Why didn't it work? What error does it give? Be more specific. What is the name of your layout file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a problem because you didn't declare a type for your variables "textTargetUri" and "targetImage".

Comment: The name of it is activity_main. That's the name of my layout file